# How to allow access to my Angular 8 app from outside network?

Tags: angular, ip, wifi

I've checked my ip addresses and I get the following:
In host file I have: 127.0.0.1       localhost
My wifi ip IPv4 is: 192.168.1.102

I've tried to start angular with: ng serve --host 198.168.1.102
And I'm getting:

```
listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 198.168.1.102:4200
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 198.168.1.102:4200
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1262:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1460:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Here is the modem/router menu with the forwarding entry:
[image]

Comment: You're doing it wrong, this is not how you host a web application. ng serve is for development purpose and not to be used for production. Buy a domain and a hosting service, you don't want to open up your IP address to the world.

Comment: I'm in development and I need to allow access to the web app

Answer (score 1):

for me works `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`, but to hit your app from outside you'll have to know your public ip, and `198.168.1.102` is your local ip - in local network

Comment: I have the connection ip from my ISP but you sure I should do 0.0.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need a public IP address that can be reached from the outside (I assume you already have it).

Then you'll have to forward some ports from the outside, through your router and to your server. In the case of your router it's probably under "NAT forwarding". With all probability, you will have to provide these information:

- Source or outside port: the port you want to use to access your service from outside (i.e. you access from outside with 8.8.8.8:444 > 444 is your source port)
- Destination or inside port: the local port of your service, in this case I imagine 4200
- Destination IP address: the local IP of your server, in this case 192.168.1.102

Some routers can't make a distinction between source and destination port, in that case they will be the same.

Comment: I've tried this with no success, is it possible to do chat?

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately I don't have any IM account.

From the updated screenshot I see you've found the correct setting page. However, you are pointing to the wrong internal IP address. This must be the IP address of the device hosting the service you want to access (192.168.1.102). Then you should be able to access from outside your network via x.x.x.x:80 with your external public IP address (check at https://www.whatismyip.com).

Make sure your external IP is public. If you can't access your IP from the outside, you will have to contact your ISP and ask them to make it public.

Answer (score 0):

If by *outside* your network you are saying **over the internet**, you'll have to forward a port from your local internet box.

You just have to open your internet box settings and forward port 80 to your device's port. For node server it's usually port 4000 but for `ng serve` it's port 4200.

Once done, just open your [public ip](https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-my-public-ip-address/) address.

Don't hesitate to read [ng serve](https://angular.io/cli/serve) doc and [port forwarding](https://stevessmarthomeguide.com/understanding-port-forwarding/) explanation.

Comment: I've attached the modem menu. Can you advise where I need to configure the forwarding and how ?

Comment: @user2304483 It might be NAT forwarding

Comment: @user2304483 if solved please put this question as solved, more readable.